How Do I Make My Object render properly?
I'm trying to Render My object, but the cel shader is not showing up. It's just rendering as a basic material. What do I do?

Give us some more details including an image of your material  Node window and share your Blend file (via https://blend-exchange.com/) and someone here might be able to help. At the moment we have no idea what settings you are using so would just be guessing.

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
